# Getting past the snake in the forest in Act 1?

Tags: broken-age

I know you can escape back the way you came, but is there a way to actually get past the snake in the forest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting past the snake is not necessary to complete Act 1. It's possible that the snake's presence is a red herring, but that seems unlikely, so I suspect it's probably going to come back in Act 2.

The snake's not the only example in Act 1 ofan area or apparent puzzle not yet accessable or solvable, for example there's at least one door on the ship that's never opened. Most of what I see on the backers' forum comes to the same assumption as above - these things will be resolved in Act 2.